# How to create table in phpmyadmin via textbox field in php

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

```
<!DOCTYPE html5>
<html>
<head>
<title>Exotic Group</title>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/3/w3.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
</head>
<body>


<h1 style="text-align: center;">EXOTIC GROUP CAMPAIGN</h1>

<!-- FORM -->
<form name="New_Campaign"  method="post" class="w3-container w3-card-4 w3-light-grey w3-text-blue w3-margin" onsubmit="alert('1 record added')">

<h2 class="w3-center">Enter your details</h2>

<!--Customer ID --> 
<div class="w3-row w3-section">
<label class="w3-text-red"><b>ENTER CAMPAIGN NAME</b></label>
  <div class="w3-col" style="width:50px; margin-top:20px"><i class="w3-xxlarge fa fa-building-o"></i>
  </div>
    <div class="w3-rest">
          <input class="w3-input w3-border" name="campaign_name" type="text" required>
    </div>
</div>

<!--SUBMIT BUTTON-->
<div class="container" style="text-align: center;">
<p><button class="w3-btn w3-green w3-round-large w3-text-shadows w3-hover-light-green" type="submit" name="submit"><b>SUBMIT</b></button></p>
</div>
</form>

<?php

//Establishing  Connection with Server
$connection = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "");

if (!$connection)
    {
        die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
    }

//Selecting Database
mysql_select_db("exotic_group", $connection);

$campaign_name = $_POST['campaign_name'];

// Create a MySQL table in the selected database
mysql_query("CREATE TABLE $campaign_name ('Cust_ID' int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
                                         'MSISDN' varchar(15) NOT NULL,
                                         'Code' varchar(8) NOT NULL,
                                         'Delivery_Status' tinyint(3) NOT NULL,
                                         'Delivery_Timestamp' datetime DEFAULT NULL,
                                         'Message_ID' varchar(20) NOT NULL,
                                         'AdViewCount' int(11) NOT NULL,
                                         'CTACount' int(11) NOT NULL,
                                          PRIMARY KEY (`Cust_ID`)
                                         ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1")

or 

die(mysql_error());

?>

</body>
</html>
```

I am getting the following error:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '('Cust_ID' int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, 'MSISDN' varchar(15) NO' at line 1

AND

> The table does not appear in the selected DB in the PHPMYADMIN interface.

Any comments are welcome.

Comment: This seems like a very bad idea. You need some serious validation on your user input and a modern mysql api. The current problem however, is that you are using the wrong kind of quotes. And an extra column for your campaign name instead of a completely new table seems to make a lot more sense.

Comment: `mysql_*` functions are deprecated, use `mysqli_*` or `PDO`

Comment: @tii-frère u first only run  this sql query in phpmyadmin & let me know it executes or not.

Comment: I have obtained this query for the column by running: 

SHOW CREATE TABLE tablename

which i have created manually

Comment: @tii-frère first remove that table from database & executes with this code

$sql = "";  // ur query.
mysql_query($sql,$connection );

Comment: it gives me unexpected beginning of statement

Comment: I just want to retrieve the tablename in a php textbox form

that is the $campaign_name obtain from the textbox campaign_name

Comment: you can create table dynamically with php code with my code.

Comment: Can you please send an example.
I am lost . . .

Comment: @tii-frère u want to retrieve the tablename for editing purpose, then use select query.

Comment: @tii-frère ur question is create table in phpmyadmin by text field form with php, can u done?

Comment: Yes create database table in phpmyadmin by text field form with php . . . i try to do it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to just remove the single quote (') form all the field.

```
mysql_query("CREATE TABLE $campaign_name (Cust_ID int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
                                     MSISDN varchar(15) NOT NULL,
                                     Code varchar(8) NOT NULL,
                                     Delivery_Status tinyint(3) NOT NULL,
                                     Delivery_Timestamp datetime DEFAULT NULL,
                                     Message_ID varchar(20) NOT NULL,
                                     AdViewCount int(11) NOT NULL,
                                     CTACount int(11) NOT NULL,
                                      PRIMARY KEY (`Cust_ID`)
                                     ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1")
```

Comment: PROBLEM SOLVE . . .TABLE ADDED SUCCESSFULLY

Comment: Thank you very much